# Knowing when a notebook has changed programmatically

Tags: notebooks

Is there any way I can programatically determine whether a notebook has unsaved edits?

Is that asterisk on the right of the notebook name represented in a notebook option or something, like `HasUnsavedEdits`?

Comment: As you suspected, the asterisk to the right of the notebook file name only appears when there are unsaved edits.

Comment: I know, I wanna know if I can programatically ask if the notebook "has the asterisk". Just edited to make it clear, my bad

Comment: Ah, OK. The edits clarified the question.

Comment: I'm curious what your need for this is. Care to share?

Comment: @EliLansey I am adding a little function on my personal package of helper functions, to allow for automatic backuping of notebooks. You can set up the frequency of saves, if you want backup copies on a subdirectory, how often do you want them, and of course, stop the task... I wanted this info to avoid backing up a file again that hasn't changed since the last backup. "FileModificationTime" and "MemoryModificationTime" also come in handy. I hate not having undos, and having powercuts and blue screens of death

Comment: Note that on OS X, the asterisk isn't next to the notebook title, but is instead a black dot in the window's close button (the red bubble in the top-left.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that

```
"ModifiedInMemory" /. NotebookInformation@SelectedNotebook[]
```

does what you want (ie, returns `False` if the notebook is saved, `True` if it is not saved). Although maybe not quite, try `NotebookInformation[CreateDocument["hi"]]`

But it seems to work once you modify a notebook that's been saved once. I could be wrong though...

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I didn't know about NotebookInformation

Comment: The document you created that way doesn't have the asterisk, nor pops up the Save Us dialog when you close it. It's a weird behaviour, but that information is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Rojo there are notebook options that you can for these things, I think. But I'm not that familiar with this sort of thing. Thanks for the accept